# Specify job properties and override properties in hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop, properties, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a hadoop (2.2.0) map-reduce job which reads text from a specified path (say INPUT_PATH), and does some processing. I don't want to hardcode the input path (since it comes from some other source which changes each week).

I believe there should be a way in hadoop to specify an xml properties file while running though the command line. How should I do it?

One way I thought was to set an environment variable which points to the location of the properties file and then read this env variable in code and subsequently read the property file. This could work because the value of the env variable can be changed each week without changing the code. But I feel this is an ugly way of loading properties and overrides.

Please let me know the least hacky way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt way to read any configuration file for input/output.

One way I can suggest is to implement a Java M/R Driver program that does the following,

- Read the configuration (XML/properties/anything) (Probably generated / updated by the other process)
- Set the Job Properties
- Submit the Job using your hadoop command (pass the configuration file as argument)

Something like this,

```
public class SampleMRDriver 
        extends Configured implements Tool {

        @Override
        public int run(
            String[] args)
            throws Exception {

            // Read from args the configuration file
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

            Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "Test Job");

            job.setJarByClass(SampleMRDriver.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setMapperClass(TestMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(TestReducer.class);

            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(prop.get("input_path")));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(prop.get("output_path")));

            boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
            return success ? 0 : 1;

        }

        public static void main(
            String[] args)
            throws Exception {

            ToolRunner.run(new BatteryAnomalyDetection(), args);
        }
}
```